# 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am getting the below screen-shot error when I try to serve my client-side code. When I am trying to run `node server/server.js`:

[image]

The below is my *server.js* code...

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-type,Accept,X-Access-Token,X-Key");

    if(req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
        res.status(200).end();
    } else {
        next();
    }

});

app.all("/api/v1/*", [require('./middlewares/validateRequest')]);
app.use("/", require("./routes"));

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    var err = new Error("Not found");
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
```

Inside my `routes/index.js`, I have the following for `get request`.

```
router.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Looks like it is reading a HTML file instead of JavaScript file. Are you getting the right JavaScript file for jQuery? Check the Net tab.

Comment: Chrome: Check Net tab. Firefox: Check Network tab. See the response for the jQuery request.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Its loading html file instead of javascript file in network tab... why so? http://localhost:3000/assets/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js this does not point to js file, but index.html... on view source

Comment: @ShankarGuru — It's serving the HTML file because you told it to. Look at your route. `res.sendfile('./public/index.html');`

Comment: @Quentin: why is not serving the js files included in the index.html...

Comment: @ShankarGuru — Because your route says to serve the index.html file.

Answer (score 22):

Usually when the browser requests a JavaScript file, the server sends an HTML file. This is due to rules like `app.get('*'...`. So we need to tell the server to send the static files first and then declare the rules, like shown below:

```
// Declare static folder to be served. It contains the JavaScript code, images, CSS, etc.
app.use(express.static('build'));

// Serve the index.html for all the other requests so that the
// router in the JavaScript application can render the necessary components
app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/build/index.html'));
  //__dirname : It will resolve to your project folder.
});
```

Comment: Worked for me, just be sure to change 'build' to your root public folder containing client js, css, etc.

Comment: ReferenceError: path is not defined

Comment: Make sure `app.use(express.static('build'))` is BEFORE your routes (exactly as in the example above even tho you might have pasted it below your routes)

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be caused by your */public/index.html* file.

When you include the JavaScript files in the *index.html* file, there's some problem with the "src" property. Thus it will return a "not found" HTML file instead of the actual JavaScript file.

Answer (score 2):

#### My folder structure

```
node(folder)
     server.js
     -client(f)
           -index.html
           -views(f)
           -js(f)
              -ctrl(f)
              -service(f)
              -app.js
              -state.js
```

and

```
app.use(express.static('client'));
app.get('/index.html', function (req, res) {

  res.sendfile(_dirname + '/index.html');

});
```

Call this from the browser: http://127.0.0.1:1956/index.html

```
var server = app.listen(1956, function (req, res) {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log("app listening at", host, port)
});
```

It's working fine for me.

Comment: Thank you! Essentially we need to point to the directory containing static files like js, css, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) application tries to compile the JavaScript files inside the public folder, that makes a mistake; you defined the public folder like this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Try to define it using a virtual directory by adding a specific virtual folder name like this:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

This should be work;

Answer (score 0):

I guess part of the problem is in your `router`

In your `routes/index.js` change the `get` request to

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
});
```

Also are you pipe-lining your assets using `gulp` or something similar? If not then how are you serving your assets?

I recommend you either [serve your assets statically](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) or use [`gulp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-express)

Comment: I am not pipe-lining my assets using gulp.... infact i thought serving index.html would server the js files too... should i include the js, css files too separately? i mean their path...

Comment: No it will not. I recommend you either serve your assets statically http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html or use `gulp`

Comment: I am already doing it right, app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"))); should it not return all the files in the public directory while serving index.html

Comment: Have you tried to change your router from * to / ??